# Laravel: hasMany relationship with multiple foreign keys?

Tags: php, laravel

I currently have a relationship like so,

```
public function transactions() {
    return $this->hasMany(UserTransaction::class, 'creator_id', 'id')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}
```

How can I fetch where `UserTransaction.creator_id` is equal to `User.id`, but also records where `UserTransaction.target_id` might be equal to `User.id`. Records will only ever be either, a user will never fill `creator_id` AND `target_id`.